# Perform arbitrary set of asynchronous tasks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

My input is streamed from another source, which makes it difficult to use `async.forEach`. I am pulling data from an API endpoint, but I have a limit of 1000 objects per request to the endpoint, and I need to get hundreds of thousands of them (basically *all* of them) and I will know they're finished when the response contains < 1000 objects. Now, I have tried this approach:

```
/* List all deposits */
var depositsAll = [];
var depositsIteration = [];
async.doWhilst(this._post(endpoint_path, function (err, response) {
     // check err

     /* Loop through the data and gather only the deposits */
     for (var key in response) {
        //do some stuff
     }
     depositsAll += depositsIteration;

     return callback(null, depositsAll);
   }, {limit: 1000, offset: 0, sort: 'desc'}),
        response.length > 1000, function (err, depositsAll) {
            // check for err
            // return the complete result
            return callback(null, depositsAll);
        });
```

With this code I get an async internal error that `iterator is not a function`. But in general I am almost sure the logic is not correct as well.

If it's not clear what I'm trying to achieve - I need to perform a request multiple times, and add the response data to a result that at the end contains all the results, so I can return it. And I need to perform requests until the response contains less than 1000 objects.

I also looked into `async.queue` but could not get the hang of it...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it like that, but if that example is from your real code you have misunderstood some of how `async` works. [`doWhilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#doWhilst) takes three arguments, each of them being a function:

1. The function to be called by `async`. Gets argument `callback` that must be called. In your case, you need to wrap `this._post` inside another function.
2. The `test` function (you would give value of `response.length > 1000`, ie. a boolean, if response would be defined)
3. The final function to be called once execution is stopped

Example with each needed function separated for readability:

```
var depositsAll = [];
var responseLength = 1000;
var self = this;

var post = function(asyncCb) {
  self._post(endpoint_path, function(err, res) {
    ...
    responseLength = res.length;
    asyncCb(err, depositsAll);
  });
}

var check = function() {
  return responseLength >= 1000;
};

var done = function(err, deposits) {
  console.log(deposits);
};

async.doWhilst(post, check, done);
```